# HIVE SQL - Pulling the Max or last record based on a date in a query

Tags: hive

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbjXm.jpg)I have an application table that i query for some results.  In that table there are multiple records for each application based on the start and end date.

I need to refine a query that will only pull the LAST reliability engineer based on the appl_support_end_date field, which if the end year will be 9999.  If there is not an active application, it will have a true end date.

I have a piece of code that works for the 9999's, but I'm having issues figuring out how to pull the last or the max date in HIVE

```
`SELECT appl_name, prod_problem_reliability_engineer, appl_support_start_date,
appl_support_end_date  from datamart_core.dm_appmaintenance_mapping
where (appl_name = 'GALAXY-WEBMETHODS-PROD' 
or appl_name = 'MD ENTERPRISE LIMS NA-PROD' 
or appl_name = 'JJCC CCV2 NA - PROD' 
or appl_name = 'MENTOR - MENTORDIRECT.COM PROD' 
or appl_name = 'CONSUMER LATIN AMERICA-ECC-PROD-PLA')
and year(appl_support_end_date) = 9999
--order by appl_name, appl_support_end_date`
--returns 4 results **consumer does not have a 9999 date
```

any thoughts or guidance is appreciated.  thanks.

Attempting multiple ideas.  I've seen where a windows function could work, but it's a new concept to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use row number function like

```
SELECT appl_name, prod_problem_reliability_engineer, appl_support_start_date, appl_support_end_date
FROM (
  SELECT appl_name, prod_problem_reliability_engineer, appl_support_start_date, appl_support_end_date,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY appl_name ORDER BY appl_support_end_date DESC) AS row_num
  FROM datamart_core.dm_appmaintenance_mapping
  WHERE appl_name IN ('GALAXY-WEBMETHODS-PROD', 'MD ENTERPRISE LIMS NA-PROD', 'JJCC CCV2 NA - PROD', 'MENTOR - MENTORDIRECT.COM PROD', 'CONSUMER LATIN AMERICA-ECC-PROD-PLA')
    AND (YEAR(appl_support_end_date) = 9999 OR appl_support_end_date IS NULL)
) ranked
WHERE row_num = 1;
```